Binding not visible in New Activity
as you can see, I am taking information from the main to the second activity. After that, when I try to print to Textview, it doesn't see it. Is there any solution?Main and
Android Studio Erorr Code Block
I'm trying ActivityMain2Binding but it's not compatible for Ikınciactivty
class IkıncıActiviy : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var binding: IkıncıActiviy
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    binding = IkıncıActiviy.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
        val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
        insets
    }
    val intent = intent
    val alinanVeri = intent.getStringExtra("veri")
    binding.textView.text = alinanVeri

}

}

Please post code as text not images. Its hard to reply this way. Also Did you enabled it in app Gradle like this android { viewBinding { enabled = true } }

I already added

What about my first point ?

So you want the written version of my code?

Welcome to stackoverflow! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Sorry, this is my first time using stack oferflow, forgive my ignorance.

Read those links and Kindly edit your question before getting downvotes.

Where are you binding your xml in your activity?

There are a few things that I have noticed are wrong. So, I will start with the basics.
To enable Data Binding or View Binding, go to your build.gradle module file.

Now you should see a file that looks something like this:
android {
    namespace = "com.example.firsttask"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.firsttask"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        viewBinding = true // enable depending upon your use case
        dataBinding = true // enable depending upon your use case
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.2"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

As shown in the above code add the lines depending on your use case
buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        viewBinding = true // enable depending upon your use case
        dataBinding = true // enable depending upon your use case
    }

Now:

goto Build>Clean Project
After the project is clean
Rebuild it, go to Build>Rebuild Project

Once these are done you should be able to access your Binding classes, if not try cleaning and invalidating the caches by going to File>Invalidate Caches...
Finally, how to access the binding file:
Binding files generally end with Binding and follow this nomenclature, the name of the XML file then ends with Binding. For example, let's say the XML file name is activity_main.xml then the relevant Binding class generated would be ActivityMainBinding. And finally then you call inflate on the file.
In your case the binding class generated should look something like this:
    // Change the Global Variable Defination
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMain2Binding

    // inside onCreate Method
    binding = ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)


Hello, actually I'm trying this out. My binding code works in the main activity, but when I created a new page and named it SecondActivity, then took information from the main to the SecondActivity, my code that works in the main doesn't work in the SecondActivityMain2Binding. When I say ActivityMain2Binding, my application crashes, but when I write the second activity there, the code doesn't work directly

Not able to understand unless you share the code.

Thanks guys, I solved the problem
I just added "val view=binding.root" and "setContentView(view)"
